# Blazor how to pass arguments to onclick function?

Tags: c#, blazor

I'd want to make button `onclick` function that takes some input.

```
<button onclick="@test(123, 456)">Check</button>

@functions
{
    public void test(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a + b);
    }
}
```

But for some reason it throws an error:

`Argument "1": Cannot convert from void to string`

Later I'd want to create those buttons in for loop like

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    <button onclick="@test(i, 5 * i)">Check</button>
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: it looks like you need to have a return type on you function, try changing void to string

Comment: @DalTron I changed void to string and added "return a" - now onClick buttons show on console ``ReferenceError: a is not define`` and after refreshing page it shows ``579`` which is 123+456 But Why?

Comment: Does it work with a lambda? 

    @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        <button onclick="@(e => test(i, 5 * i))">Check</button>
    }

Comment: @bcwhims Perfectly! Please write it as an answer!

Comment: Related: [`@onclick=“(() => SomeMethod(parameter))”`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609923/onclick-somemethodparameter)

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Try it with a lambda. You're binding the `onclick` to the result of the function rather than the function itself.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var buttonNumber = i;
    <button @onclick="@(e => test(buttonNumber, 5 * buttonNumber))">Check</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks and I also found the Blazor docs helpful on this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I've tried this but keep getting the error `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: When that happens you need to explicitly create the `EventCallback` using the `EventCallback.Factory`. Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallbackfactory?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Quotes are not required, this is not js!

Answer (score 76):

I try this and worked

```
@onclick="(() => FunctionName(argument))"
```

like

```
@onclick="(() => GetDetail(item.UserId))"
```

Got idea from https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/15956 .

Comment: `@onclick="() => FunctionName(argument)"` works too, no need for extra parentheses

Answer (score 17):

At Sign on `onclick` specifies it's a C# function:

```
@onclick = "@(() => test(i, 5*i))"
```

Comment: Even though the code is fine, the explanation makes no sense. There's no ampersand (&) in the code.

Comment: I said "At" not "Amper" ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here is full syntax which contains:

1. Asynchronous method.
2. MouseEventArgs passed.
3. Custom parameter.

```razor
<button @onclick="@(async (args) => await ButtonEvent(args, 5))">My Button</button>

@code {
   async Task ButtonEvent(MouseEventArgs args, int CustomParameter)
   {
            
   }
}
```

Comment: Correct but inefficient. You can remove the async and await from the lambda. That makes it a tiny bit smaller and faster.

Comment: But when your ButtonEvent needs asynchronous handling (e.g. it calls async methods), then it is the simplest solution (without creating Task objects).

Comment: Without those 2 keywords it does exactly the same (async) thing. Search for "eliding async await".

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="button" @onclick="@(() => functionname(paramvalue))" class="....." value="DoSomething" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The following both input as well as button typed worked for me.

```
<td>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete"
    @onclick="(() => this.DeleteTodoItem(todoItem.Id))"  />
</td>
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" 
    @onclick="(() => this.DeleteTodoItem(todoItem.Id))">Delete</button>
</td>
```