# @onclick="(() => SomeMethod(parameter))"

Tags: lambda, blazor, .net-core-3.0

I am looking into Blazor and I stumbpled on this expression:

```
 @onclick="(() => SomeMethod(parameter))"
```

I cannot find/google anywhere what does this (I guess lambda) expression is actually doing. Can anybody explain me please this part: `() =>` and why to use it and where?

**EDIT:**

What is the difference between the above and this:

```
 @onclick="SomeMethod(parameter)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`() =>()`  is basically a lambda function.

Imagine you have a function

```
delegate (int foo) { return foo*2};
```

this can be rewritten as

```
(int foo)=>{return foo*2};
```

which can be shortened to

```
 foo=>foo*2;
```

Here your `onlclick` method executes `SomeMethod` which takes in a `parameter`

Why to use ? 
For creating simple and easy to use event handlers,callbacks delegates etc.

Reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: Why cannot I just use this: ' @onclick="SomeMethod(parameter)" ?

Comment: OnClick is an event handler and it expects a delegate , not the result of a function.

Comment: Ok, but in Blazor right now, if I have @onclick="MyMethod" then it fires my method. I have just tested it. so I am still not sure when to use what :/

Comment: Absolutely MyMethod is a function . Try this MyMethod() . It wont .

Answer (score 3):

#### Option one, lambda function (anonymous function):

```
    @onclick="( ( ) => SomeMethod(parameter) ) "
       ^         ^     ^
       |         |     |
       (1)       (2)   (3)
```

When user clicks on control (1), the function (2) will be executed. (3) is the body of the function (2). This is an anonymous function, it has no name, because this only has parenthesys:   `__no_name_function__ ( )`.

#### Option two, expression:

```
    @onclick="SomeMethod(parameter)"
       ^             ^
       |             |
       (1)           (2)
```

When user clicks on control (1), the result of expression (2) will be invoked. This function should return a delegate.

#### Sample

Play with this sample at [blazorfiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/rsqm23mo) for a bit to understand it better.

```
<h1>@parameter</h1>

<button @onclick="@(() => SomeMethod1(parameter))" >button 1</button>

<button @onclick="SomeMethod2(parameter)" >button 2</button>

<p>@theResult</p>

@code
{
    int parameter = 5;
    string theResult = "";

    void SomeMethod1(int p)
    {
        parameter++;
        theResult = $"SomeMethod1 called p={p}";
    }

    Action SomeMethod2(int p)
    {        
        return SomeAction;
    }

    void SomeAction()
    {
        theResult = $"Action called parameter={parameter}";
        parameter++;
    }
}
```

Notice that is almost the same this:

```
<button @onclick="SomeMethod2(parameter)" >button 2</button>
```

than this:

```
<button @onclick="SomeAction" >button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this pattern:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" @onclick="@(() => SomeMethod("my string"))" />
```

when you want to call a method and pass it a parameter. Behind the scene, the compiler creates an EventCallback struct that provides the appropriate delegate type that encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and returns void

When you want to call a method that has no parameters use this pattern:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" @onclick="@(SomeMethod1)" />

(not recommended, embedded in a Razor expression)
```

Or simply use the most common usage:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" @onclick="@SomeMethod1" />
```

This is also possible:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" @onclick="SomeMethod1" />
```

(The **@** sign is not necessary here any longer, but you may see most developers use it though; out of habit, as this was necessary in the old days)

hope this helps...

Comment: @onclick="@(() => SomeMethod("my string"))" --> this will not be validated in VS in syntax. What I get as error is this: