# How to send an object through @change="" (instead of sending value) when using select element

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

new to Blazor and I have a simple question

In my Blazor app, I have a simple select element:

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" @onchange="ItemSelected">
 <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  
  @foreach(var item in Items)
  {
    <option value="@item.Id"> @item.Name </option>
  }
</select>
```

The idea is when a user selects an option, I want to get the object instead of the key, here is the function:

```
List<object> ItemContainer = new List<object>(); 
private void ItemSelected(ChangeEventArgs obj) {
  ...
  ItemContainer.Add(obj); 
}
```

How do I capture the object instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@onclick="(() => SomeMethod(parameter))"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609923/onclick-somemethodparameter)

Comment: @Yogi No, it explains what Lambda function is but it doesn't show how to pass objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@page "/"


<select @onchange="ItemSelected" class="form-select">
    <option value="null">Select...</option>

    @foreach (var option in options)
    {
        <option @key="option" value="@option.ID">@option.Value</option>
    }
</select>
       
  
@code {
    private Option option;

    private List<Option> options = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new Option { ID = i, Value = $"Option{i}" }).ToList();

    private void ItemSelected(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(args.Value.ToString(), out int selectedID))
        {

            option = options.Where(o => o.ID == selectedID).FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine(option.ID.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(option.Value);
        }
    }


    public class Option
    {
#nullable enable
        public int? ID { get; set; }
#nullable disable
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

}
```

UPDATE:

> Hi, sorry for bothering you but I am stuck a bit on something. How do I avoid Option in my code? Because I already have an Item class private IEnumerable Items { get; set; } = new List(); is there a way to substitute both? thanks

`Option` is the class name given by me. You can give it whatever name you want. You may define your class like the following instead:

```
public class ItemDTO
        {
    #nullable enable
            public int? Id { get; set; }
    #nullable disable
            public string Name{ get; set; }
        }
```

Note: If you're using .Net 6.0, you may remove the #nullable directive

Update:

Don't use `Task.Run`
Change this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(GetItems); 
        Client = _client.Get(Id);
    }
 
    private void GetItems()
    {
        Items = _item.GetAll();  
    }
```

To:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
        Client = _client.Get(Id);
        Items = _item.GetAll(); 
   }
```

Change this:

```
private IEnumerable<ItemDTO> Items { get; set; } = new List<ItemDTO>();
```

To:

```
private IList<ItemDTO> Items { get; set; } = new List<ItemDTO>();
```

The above changes are rather cosmetics than functional. I've no way to verify this as I only read the code; I do not view and run it in an IDE.

Anyhow, the following code snippet is incorrect and as a result  leads to an error:

```
var  option = ItemDTO.Where(o => o.Id == 
                                selectedID).FirstOrDefault();
```

The code above is suppose to query the the list of ItemDTO objects, and return a single object whose Id property is equivalent to the value we pass to the method (ItemSelected) in which the code is executed. The list of ItemDTO objects, defined as `Items` should be used for searching the selected item; that is, you should use:

```
`Items.Where`
```

Instead of:

`ItemDTO.Where`

`ItemDTO` is a class name or a type...

This is how your code should be:

```
var  option = Items.Where(o => o.Id == 
                                    selectedID).FirstOrDefault();
```

May God bless your code ;}

Comment: Hi I tried your script and I get this error: `InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'foo.com.Pages.InvoiceCreate' does not have a property matching the name 'ID'.`

Comment: No, you didn't try my code. You've got to execute the code snippet as is. Do you see 'foo.com.Pages.InvoiceCreate' in my code ? No, you don't. If you try to adapt your code with mine, you'll have to have a property named `ID` wherever you use it.

Comment: Why would I lie to you? I copy pasted your code into one of my Blazor pages, which is called `InvoiceCreate`. I removed all code in the page and only modified `@page "/"` to `@page "/test"` so I can access it through that page

Comment: Your comment is vague. Please, create an answer with all the code involved. You can delete it later on.

Comment: Hi, sorry for bothering you but I am stuck a bit on something. How do I avoid `Option` in my code? Because I already have an Item class `private IEnumerable<ItemDTO> Items { get; set; } = new List<ItemDTO>();` is there a way to substitute both? thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to do that...

Comment: Hi thanks for the update, this thing is driving me crazy for 3 days. My fault, I jumped to blazor without learning enough C#. The problem is I can't seem to replace Option with Item. It gives me an error no matter how misplace it. I built my CRUD up bit this is the only part I am stuck in. If you can take a look, I here is a pastebin which contains the file the code is running in. I put your code at last : https://pastebin.com/GNN3qBE7 and the ItemRepository if you are curious https://pastebin.com/KDhUUUKk

Comment: I've added an update section to my answer.

Comment: Well this is the farthest I have gone to make it work, by that I mean there is only one error: https://i.ibb.co/z4JTRzH/bb.png sorry but I am thinking this is all it takes to fix it,

Comment: Try this: return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Item>, IEnumerable<ItemDTO>>(_db.Items).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly.  `ChangeEventArgs` returns a string as it's `Value` object.

You need to do something like this:

```
@page "/"

<select @onchange=OnSelect >
    @foreach (var country in Countries)
    {
        <option value="@country.Id" selected="@this.IsSelected(country)">@country.Name</option>
    }
</select>

<div>
    Selected : @this.SelectedCountry 
</div>

@code {
    private Country? country;
    private string SelectedCountry => this.country?.Name ?? "None Selected";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // to demo selected is working
        this.country = this.Countries[1];
    }

    private void OnSelect(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(e.Value?.ToString(), out int value))
            country = Countries.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Id == value);
    }

    private bool IsSelected(Country c)
        => c == this.country;

    public List<Country> Countries = new List<Country>
        {
            new Country { Id =44, Name = "UK" },
            new Country { Id =61, Name = "France" },
            new Country { Id =1, Name = "USA" },

        };

    public class Country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is something in this code that is not displaying the page. I even created a `Test.razor`  with `@page "/test"` and it does not show the page, I get the `Sorry, there's nothing at this address.` error

Comment: @user7342807, this code is fine. Just copy it as is and paste it into the Index component, after you've deleted the previous content. The same with my code snippets. Both are complete and working. Copy and test them. Then learn what they do and how, and then edit your code accordingly.

Comment: Create a clean Blazor Server template solution and overwrite the code in `Index.razor` with this code and it WILL work.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't type well now to check the syntax exactly, but maybe something like:

`@onchange="(e)=> ItemSelected(Items.Single(i=> i.ID.ToString() == e.Value.ToString()))"`

And then

`private void ItemSelected(YourItemClass SelectedItem) {}`

Comment: Hi how do I create the `YourItemClass`?  I am fairly new to Blazor

Comment: You're running a `foreach` loop on a collection called `Items`. But I can't see what class `Items` is a `List` of. Use that class whatever it is.