# @Onclick Razor Event not being called

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web, razor

```
<div class="TitleBar"> </div>
<div class="Title"></div>
<div class="Side1">
    <div class="Link" >
        @foreach(var _blog in Blogs)
        {
            <a href="Blog" class="button" style="text-decoration: none;">
                <button @onclick = "() => Click(_blog)" >@_blog.Title</button>
            </a>
        }
     </div>
</div>
@code
{
    void Click(blog _blog)
    {
        string fileLocation = _blog.Location;
        string allText;

        using(StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileLocation))
        {
            allText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        using(StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"C:\Users\14025\source\repos\bluebeanwebsiteoooyeah\bluebeanwebsiteoooyeah\wwwroot\TextFile.txt"))
        {
            writer.Write(allText);
        }
    }
}
```

Just trying to call the Click event. It's not getting called when I click the button. In fact none of the `@` events are working.

I've tried changing the `@events`. I've tried only using the hyperlink and a `@onpointerenter` event. I've tried testing the `@onpointerenter` event on the button. I expect to call the click function changing the text file to the blog that I want.

Comment: Just a thought. It might be a good idea to test if wiring up a more simple function would work correctly. e.g. There is a code snippet here with a basic hello world style example. Does trying to run this code work correctly?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611692/3097516

Comment: Are you certain the event isn’t getting called and then failing? Trying to write to an OS path from a web page is kind of dubious—could that be the issue?