# Blazor WebAssembly button onclick not triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

TL;DR:
I've figured out I was confusing Blazor App Types and forgot to add `@rendermode InteractiveServer`.
I've a Client WebAssembly Blazor app and have a problem with onclick method not being triggered after clicking on button. This Blazor WebAssembly was added to existing ASP.NET Core WebAPI. It's .NET 8. 
I've a dynamically created table containing some data fetched from service.
Code doing this below:

```
private void FetchMails() {
    APIResponse result = MailArchiveService.GetMailMessages();
    if(!result.Success) {
        StatusMessage = result.GetStatusString();
    } else {
        Data = result.GetContent<List<MailDTO>>();
    }
}
```

APIResponse is a wrapper for communication between services, controllers and this Blazor app.
It works and provided data are valid and displays correctly. My table generation looks like that:

```
@if (Data == null){
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
} else {
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sender</th>
                <th>Recipient</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>TemplateType</th>
                <th>Sent</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var record in Data) {
                <tr>
                    <td>@record.Sender.Email</td>
                    <td>@record.Recipient.Email</td>
                    <td>@record.Subject</td>
                    <td>@record.TemplateType.ToString()</td>
                    <td>@record.SentTime?.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")</td>
                    <td>
                        <button @onclick="() => ViewMailContent(record.ID)">View</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

My onclick method looks like this:

```
public void ViewMailContent(int id) {
    Console.WriteLine($"ViewMailContent called with ID: {id}");
    //Display message content to user
}
```

My problem is that when I click the button nothing happens.
I've added this WriteLine and placed breakpoint there and it's not even entering this method.
For test reasons I've added another button outside of this table with const id and then it's working correctly. I do not get any bug, the app seems to do nothing, but don't freezes (I still can change tabs, and do other things).

I've tried solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297711/blazor-how-to-pass-arguments-to-onclick-function).
But it's not working.

I've tried changing the button in such ways:

- Changed onclick to something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297989/13019353):
  `<button @onclick:event="onclick" @onclick="@(e => ViewMailContent(record.ID))">View</button>`
- Changing return type to EventCallback: 
  `<button @onclick="ViewMailContent(record.ID)">View</button>` 
  It was triggered when the page was loaded without user clicing
- Adding mouseEventArgs (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75676004/13019353)): 
  `<button @onclick="@(async (args) => ViewMailContent(record.ID))">View</button>`
  `<button @onclick="@(async (args) => ViewMailContent(args, record.ID))">View</button>`
  Nothing changed
- Adding such event (GPT suggestion): 
  `<button @onclick:event="onclick" @onclick="() => ViewMailContent(record.ID)">View</button>`
  Nothing changed
- Temporarily replaced handler with console.log:
  `<button onclick="console.log('Clicked @record.ID')">View</button>` 
  I can see the message in browser's dev tools.

I got stuck and do not know what I'm doing wrong. I'm pretty new to Blazor.

Comment: what version .net

Comment: If you are under .net8 have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/q/58196812/5228202 ?

Comment: @Cfun Yes, it's dotnet8. I will check the link tomorrow and see if it works. I'm updating the post to contain dotnet version.

Comment: @RBee It's .NET 8 now. API was originally created in .NET 6, but I've updated the whole app to use .NET 8 before adding Blazor.

Comment: Are you surte it is a  _Blazor WebAssembly __Standalone___ app ?

Comment: @ℍℍ I had existing ASP.NET Core WebAPI. I wanted to add a Blazor to this, so I've created new temporary solution and tried VisualStudio Blazor templates. I've chosen BlazorApp template, because it seemed to be the easiest one to integrate with my API and this worked. I've tested it before and after integrating with my WebAPI and all of the template pages worked. I've even edited the Counter.razor in order to pass int to it's handler: `<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => IncrementCount(2)">Click me</button>' `private void IncrementCount(int offset)`. It works after this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the I didn't have this: 
`@rendermode InteractiveServer`
After adding it everything works just fine.

Comment: You might want to read up on rendermodes, because in your question you mention BlazorWebassembly but your answer is InteractiveServer.

Comment: @RBee Ok, thanks I will definitely check it out. I have no previous experience with Blazor. It was meant to be only a WebAPI, but then the need of providing simple GUI for administrative and maintenance services came up and I thought Blazor will be the quickest solution.

Answer (score 1):

The handler you have wired up in:

```cs
@onclick="() => ViewMailContent(record.ID)"
```

has the delegate signature:

```cs
Task MethodName(int id)
```

But the method you've supplied has different signature.

To match your handler you need to:

```cs
<button @onclick="(e) => ViewMailContent(e, record.ID)">View</button>
```

Or you can make your handler:

```cs
public void ViewMailContent(int id) {
    Console.WriteLine($"ViewMailContent called with ID: {id}");
    //Display message content to user
}
```

Also be careful with the `void`.  If this is an `async` method it should be:

```cs
public async Task ViewMailContent(int id) {
    Console.WriteLine($"ViewMailContent called with ID: {id}");
    //Do some async work here.
}
```

Comment: In base version there are no MouseEventArgs, because I don't need them. There is only int and it's not async. I've added this MouseEventArgs and made it async Task because it was suggested in some answers, but it didn't help. Thank's for help.